# QDialogButtonBox button Ok not woking after connecting

Tags: signals-slots, qt-designer, qdialog

I have a mainWindow class that calls a function `mainWIndow::ShowDialogBox()` when double clicked on the QTabBar. The dialog box shows up, but it isn't connecting the buttons. I have the connect calls in ShowDialogBox. It gives me a red underline on connect saying

```
 no instance of overloaded function "MainWindow::connect" matches the argument list"
```

This is my code

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
 {
    if (object == mTabWidget->getTabBar() && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick) 
    {
        qDebug()<<"dblclk";

    ShowDialogBox();

    }

    return QObject::eventFilter(object, event);
}

//Show dialog box when double clicked on QTabBar
void MainWindow::ShowDialogBox(){

    QDialog dialog;
    QVBoxLayout layout(&dialog);
    QLineEdit editLine;
    layout.addWidget(&editLine);

     QDialogButtonBox *dialogButton = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok );
     connect(dialogButton, SIGNAL(accepted()), dialog, SLOT(accept())); //this 'connect' is underlined
     layout.addWidget(dialogButton);
     dialog.setLayout(&layout);


    if(dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        mTabWidget->setTabText(0, editLine.text());
    }

  }
```

I have added the signals and slot in mainWindow.h as

```
private slots:
    void accept();

signals:

    void accepted();
```

I have spend hours on this but no luck. I am new to Qt.

Comment: Do you have any `MainWindow::connect` functions implemented by you?

Comment: @luliu : No. Do we have to? as i said I am new so can't really figure it out.

Comment: No...does `MainWindow` inherit `QMainWindow`? What happens if you replace `connect` with `QObject::connect`?

Comment: @luliu Yes, it inherits `QMainWindow`. And when I replace connect with         `QObject::connect` it gives the error no instance of overloaded function `QObject::connect` matches the argument list"

Comment: Have you tried running `qmake`(Build->Run qmake) and then doing a rebuild?

Comment: I am using cMake and no I haven't tried because it doensn't complile. when I try to compile it with that connect call, it gives me this error `Error 120 error C2664: 'bool QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'QDialog' to 'const QObject *'
`

Comment: Please see my answer. Feedback would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line:

```
connect(dialogButton, SIGNAL(accepted()), dialog, SLOT(accept()));
```

should be:

```
connect(dialogButton, SIGNAL(accepted()), &dialog, SLOT(accept()));
```

Because the third parameter has to be a memory address(pointer).

Comment: Thanks. The connect works now but then the window immediately shuts down giving an error saying `Unhandled exception` and the breakpoint is in file qscopedpointer.h in line  `inline T *data() const
    {
        return d;
    }`

Comment: I am unable to understand why its giving me an error. Does it have to do anything with signals and slots? Because I have just declared the slots, not defined them bacause they are standard slots. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: @user2 I'm not 100% sure but it is possible that the problem is caused by line `dialog.setLayout(&layout);`. Reading the `QWidget::setLayout` documentation which says that `An alternative to calling this function is to pass this widget to the layout's constructor.` will tell you that passing `dialog` to `layout`'s constructor and also calling `setLayout` is equivalent to setting the layout twice which is a very bad idea in `Qt`. I recommend you either remove line `dialog.setLayout(&layout);` or change line `QVBoxLayout layout(&dialog);` to `QVBoxLayout layout;`. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: i tried what you said, It still gives the same unhandled exception error. And apart from that, when  I have slot declaration as `accept();` it doesn't complile and gives an unresolved external symbol error for accept. BUt when I change it to `accept(){}` it compiles but gives that unhandled exception again at runtime.

Comment: @user2 Did you implement `accept()` in the `cpp` file?

Comment: this is what error says: Unhandled exception at 0x64f5566a (QtGuid4.dll) in easypaint.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

Comment: @user2 The problems are not coming from the code you already posted. Can you post the whole source code of `MainWindow`? Otherwise I don't think I can figure out what happened.

Comment: No i did not implement accept in cpp because I dont know how to. Moreover, i thought there is nothing that accept() does because everything is done in the ShowDialogBox()

Comment: Well, if you have a function declared in the header file and you don't implement it, you will get a link error...just like you did. These are basic `OOP` principles you should know before diving into `Qt`. The response I wrote you covers the issue the question was posted for, which was solving the `connect` error and it solves the problem. These being said you should either mark the answer as accepted and post another question regarding the rest of the issues or edit the post providing the full `MainWindow` class implementation because no one can solve a problem which doesn't know exists.

Comment: Yeah I fixed this problem. Thanks. The thing was, while trying different possibilities I commented out the ShowDialogBox() in eventFilter and pasted all its code in eventFilter. It should have worked as well. But anyways, when I removed it, It works Fine and name changes.

Comment: @user2 I'm glad you figured it out!